# Setting env variable on Heroku when several apps using figaro

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, environment-variables

Rails 4.0.4 
Ruby 2.1.1
Mac OS X 10.9.2 Maverick

This command worked well until I added another remote.

```
rake figaro:heroku 
 !    Multiple apps in folder and no app specified.
 !    Specify app with --app APP.
 !    Multiple apps in folder and no app specified.
 !    Specify app with --app APP.
```

I have tried using the --app  but that won't work

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run the following command

```
rake figaro:heroku[myapp]
```

Comment: You may have to escape the brackets if you're using zsh: `rake figaro:heroku\[myapp\]`.

Answer (score 0):

heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=key --app safe-planet-29288

Comment: some description to accompany the answer would have helped understand it better.

Comment: Hi, Damien. Sure: If you have several apps in heroku, you have to specified the app when you tried to set an environment variable. this is why you run the command in the console: "$ heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=key --app safe-planet-29288" Where "safe-planet-29288" is the application name given by heroku, you should replace it for yours.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: `figaro heroku:set -e production -a myapp`